# How to make a sliding tab calendar timeline like in Fitocracy?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm trying to implement sliding tabs that are based on a calendar and look like a timeline. Here's an example from [Fitocracy on the play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitocracy.app&hl=en):

How would you go about implementing it? I've tried looking online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd use a `ViewPager` with a custom `PagerAdapter`, where `getCount()` returns an obscenely large number and you start in the middle, mapping positions to dates. Then, choose your favorite tabbed indicator for a `ViewPager`.